# How to rebuild newlib and newlib-nano of GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain

Tags: c++, c, arm, toolchain, newlib

I downloaded the toolchain “*gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update-win32-sha1.exe*” (Windows) from https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads and installed it on my Windows 10 PC.

The installation folder contains a release.txt in “*../share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/*” which tells:

> This release includes the following items:
>
> - newlib and newlib-nano :
>     git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git commit 0d79b021a4ec4e6b9aa1a9f6db0e29a137005ce7

And also the readme.txt in “*../share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/*” contains:

> - C Libraries usage *
>
> This toolchain is released with two prebuilt C libraries based on
>   newlib: one is the standard newlib (libc.a) and the other is
>   newlib-nano (libc_nano.a) for code size.

Now I want exactly rebuild all the libc.a and libc_nano.a contained in “*../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb*”

At the moment I can build on Ubuntu with “*gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update-linux.tar.bz2*”

```
$ # Downloaded newlib-cygwin (with corresponding hash) into folder newlib-cygwin
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../newlib-cygwin/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls
$ make
```

**How do I have to configure the newlib to build the exact copies of libc.a and for libc_nano.a contained in gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update-linux.tar.bz2?**

```
$ # Downloaded newlib-cygwin (with corresponding hash) into folder newlib-cygwin
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../newlib-cygwin/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --???
$ make
```

Comment: You have to configure it the way you want. If you want newlib supplied syscall calls then don't disable them. Does `../newlib-cygwin/configure --target=arm-none-eabi` fail to run on windows? What's the error?

Comment: No it don't fail to run on windows but with cygwin the build it takes very long to build the library. Yes, for me it's clear that I can configure it like I want, but I like to configure it exactly like the GNU ARM Toolchain. The only problem is I don't know where I can find this configuration options.

Answer (score 15):

If i understand you correctly, a more detailed question is:
What configure options did 'GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain' developers used when building newlib libraries shipped in gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update-linux.tar.bz2 archive?
These ones for newlib:

`--target=arm-none-eabi --enable-newlib-io-long-long --enable-newlib-register-fini --enable-newlib-retargetable-locking --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls --disable-nls`

And these ones for newlib-nano:

`--target=arm-none-eabi --enable-newlib-reent-small --disable-newlib-fvwrite-in-streamio --disable-newlib-fseek-optimization --disable-newlib-wide-orient --enable-newlib-nano-malloc --disable-newlib-unbuf-stream-opt --enable-lite-exit --enable-newlib-global-atexit --enable-newlib-nano-formatted-io --disable-nls`

How I got it? Let's walk through the process:
These packages are build on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded), where from you find all the [builds](https://launchpad.net/~team-gcc-arm-embedded/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+builds?build_state=built) that took place on lanuchpad. I picked [gcc-arm-none-eabi 6-2017q2-1 from 2017-10-24](https://launchpad.net/~team-gcc-arm-embedded/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/13612999). There i can find the [buildlog](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/342606252/buildlog_ubuntu-artful-amd64.gcc-arm-none-eabi_6-2017q2-1~artful1_BUILDING.txt.gz). I grepped the buildlog with `| grep "^+ " | grep "configure " | grep 'src/newlib'` and i was left with:

`+ /<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/src/newlib/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/install-native --infodir=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-newlib-io-long-long --enable-newlib-register-fini --enable-newlib-retargetable-locking --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls --disable-nls
+ /<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/src/newlib/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/build-native/target-libs --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls --enable-newlib-reent-small --disable-newlib-fvwrite-in-streamio --disable-newlib-fseek-optimization --disable-newlib-wide-orient --enable-newlib-nano-malloc --disable-newlib-unbuf-stream-opt --enable-lite-exit --enable-newlib-global-atexit --enable-newlib-nano-formatted-io --disable-nls`

A bit of Sherlock Holmes and i deduced that the second line is newlib configured to build as newlib-nano (`--enable-newlib-reent-small`), the first is newlib configured to build as full newlib.
To answer your topic question, to recompile newlib and newlib-nano the same way pass the options I have posted above to newlib `./configure` script.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I will try today. I think another possible to search in https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/arm-none-eabi-gcc-build/blob/master/scripts/container-gcc-functions-source.sh

Comment: For newer versions of the ARM toolchain that are not on launchpad, on ARM's download page if you download the "Source Tarball" there is a file called build-toolchain.sh and there is section that has the configuration options for newlib and newlib-nano. You can find them by searching the script for $SRCDIR/$NEWLIB/configure and $SRCDIR/$NEWLIB_NANO/configure respectively

Comment: @tbejos The configure commands are also in the binary packages release from ARM. They have a file in the root of the archive that ends in the `*arm-none-eabi-manifest.txt`. That particular file has the set of configuration flags for gcc, newlib and other bundled packages.

Answer (score 2):

Hints about how the compiler was configured are found in:

- `$COMPILER_PATH/arm-none-eabi/include/newlib.h`
- `$COMPILER_PATH/arm-none-eabi/include/newlib-nano/newlib.h`

The `#define`s there have a close correspondence to the options that were passed to 'configure', when newlib was built.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it would be useful to give the default configuration of the ARM built newlib/newlib-nano as of 2023 (for GCC 10):

For Newlib:

> --enable-newlib-io-long-long 
> --enable-newlib-io-c99-formats 
> --enable-newlib-reent-check-verify 
> --enable-newlib-register-fini 
> --enable-newlib-retargetable-locking 
> --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls 
> --disable-nls

For Newlib-nano:

> --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls 
> --enable-newlib-reent-check-verify 
> --enable-newlib-reent-small 
> --enable-newlib-retargetable-locking 
> --disable-newlib-fvwrite-in-streamio 
> --disable-newlib-fseek-optimization 
> --disable-newlib-wide-orient 
> --enable-newlib-nano-malloc 
> --disable-newlib-unbuf-stream-opt 
> --enable-lite-exit 
> --enable-newlib-global-atexit 
> --enable-newlib-nano-formatted-io 
> --disable-nls

Ref: https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/compilers-and-libraries-forum/53310/gcc-arm-none-eabi-what-were-the-newlib-compilation-options